# How to produce matrix using dataframe row values

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| name | session | sessionvote | voter response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tim | 116 | 1 | Y |
| Tim | 116 | 2 | N |
| Tim | 117 | 1 | Y |
| Tim | 117 | 2 | Y |
| Dave | 117 | 1 | N |
| Dave | 117 | 2 | Y |
| Larry | 116 | 1 | Y |
| Larry | 116 | 2 | Y |
| Larry | 117 | 1 | Y |
| John | 117 | 1 | N |

`name` refers to the subjects, `session` refers to the meeting (in which multiple votes can be held), `sessionvote` refers to the ID or vote number for that session, and `voter response` refers to the subjects' vote on that specific session vote.

I want to compute a similarity score for between each pair of users, based on their vote similarity, using only the data from votes they both were present for. The similarity score should be computed like this (# of same vote response/# of votes both subjects were present for). For example, Tim and Larry were both present for three of the same votes (116-1, 116-2, 117-1), their responses were the same for two of those votes (116-1, 117-1), but differed for the third vote they both were present for (116-2). To compute their score, it would be 2 (# of Tim and Larry's shared responses)/3 (number of votes both Tim and Larry were present for), giving them a .66 similarity score.

I believe the simplest way to do this would be to produce a matrix that looks something like this:

|  | Tim | Dave | Larry | John |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tim | 1 | .5 | .66 | 0 |
| Dave | .5 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Larry | .66 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| John | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Though I can conceptualize what I want it to look like, I'm not sure how to turn this dataframe into a matrix based on these rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I have included the `dput` output below. This is a subset of the data I am trying to use. The full dataset is much larger.

```
structure(list(name = c("YOUNG, Donald Edwin", "SENSENBRENNER, Frank James, Jr.", 
"ROGERS, Harold Dallas (Hal)", "SMITH, Christopher Henry", "HOYER, Steny Hamilton", 
"KAPTUR, Marcia Carolyn (Marcy)", "VISCLOSKY, Peter", "DeFAZIO, Peter Anthony", 
"LEWIS, John R.", "PRICE, David Eugene", "UPTON, Frederick Stephen", 
"PELOSI, Nancy", "PALLONE, Frank, Jr.", "ENGEL, Eliot Lance", 
"LOWEY, Nita M.", "NEAL, Richard Edmund", "SCHIFF, Adam", "DAVIS, Susan A.", 
"LYNCH, Stephen F.", "McCOLLUM, Betty", "GRAVES, Samuel", "LANGEVIN, James", 
"WILSON, Addison Graves (Joe)", "LARSEN, Richard Ray (Rick)", 
"CLAY, William Lacy, Jr.", "ROGERS, Mike Dennis", "GRIJALVA, Raúl M.", 
"NUNES, Devin", "SÁNCHEZ, Linda T.", "DIAZ-BALART, Mario", "SCOTT, David", 
"CASE, Ed", "KING, Steve", "RUPPERSBERGER, C. A. (Dutch)", "BUTTERFIELD, George Kenneth, Jr. (G.K.)", 
"TURNER, Michael R.", "RYAN, Timothy J.", "COLE, Tom", "BURGESS, Michael C.", 
"CARTER, John R.", "BISHOP, Robert (Rob)", "COSTA, Jim", "WASSERMAN SCHULTZ, Debbie", 
"LIPINSKI, Daniel", "CLEAVER, Emanuel, II", "FORTENBERRY, Jeff", 
"HIGGINS, Brian", "FOXX, Virginia Ann", "McHENRY, Patrick T.", 
"GOHMERT, Louie", "GREEN, Al", "McCAUL, Michael T.", "CONAWAY, K. Michael", 
"MARCHANT, Kenny", "CUELLAR, Henry", "McMORRIS RODGERS, Cathy", 
"MOORE, Gwendolynne S. (Gwen)", "MATSUI, Doris", "SIRES, Albio", 
"McNERNEY, Jerry", "MCCARTHY, Kevin", "LAMBORN, Doug", "PERLMUTTER, Ed", 
"COURTNEY, Joe", "CASTOR, Kathy", "BUCHANAN, Vernon G.", "JOHNSON, Hank", 
"LOEBSACK, Dave", "YARMUTH, John", "SARBANES, John", "WALBERG, Tim", 
"SMITH, Adrian", "CLARKE, Yvette Diane", "JORDAN, Jim", "COHEN, Stephen", 
"FOSTER, Bill", "WELCH, Peter", "LATTA, Robert E.", "WITTMAN, Robert J.", 
"CARSON, André", "BILIRAKIS, Gus", "SCALISE, Steve", "SPEIER, Karen Lorraine Jacqueline (Jackie)", 
"KIRKPATRICK, Ann", "McCLINTOCK, Tom", "HIMES, James A.", "POSEY, Bill", 
"GUTHRIE, Brett", "PINGREE, Chellie", "LUETKEMEYER, Blaine", 
"TITUS, Alice (Dina)", "LUJÁN, Ben Ray", "TONKO, Paul", "FUDGE, Marcia L.", 
"SCHRADER, Kurt", "THOMPSON, Glenn", "ROE, David P. (Phil)", 
"OLSON, Pete", "CONNOLLY, Gerald E. (Gerry)", "QUIGLEY, Mike", 
"CHU, Judy", "GARAMENDI, John", "DEUTCH, Theodore E. (Ted)", 
"GRAVES, Tom", "HUNTER, Duncan Duane", "REED, Thomas W. II", 
"SEWELL, Terri", "GOSAR, Paul", "SCHWEIKERT, David", "CRAWFORD, Rick", 
"WOMACK, Steve", "BASS, Karen", "TIPTON, Scott", "WEBSTER, Daniel A.", 
"WILSON, Frederica", "WOODALL, Rob", "SCOTT, Austin", "KINZINGER, Adam", 
"BUCSHON, Larry", "RICHMOND, Cedric", "HARRIS, Andy", "KEATING, William R.", 
"HUIZENGA, Bill", "AMASH, Justin", "PALAZZO, Steven", "HARTZLER, Vicky", 
"LONG, Billy", "JOHNSON, Bill", "STIVERS, Steve", "GIBBS, Bob", 
"KELLY, Mike", "MARINO, Thomas A.", "CICILLINE, David N.", "DUNCAN, Jeff", 
"FLEISCHMANN, Chuck", "DESJARLAIS, Scott", "FLORES, Bill", "HERRERA BEUTLER, Jaime", 
"McKINLEY, David", "DUFFY, Sean", "GRIFFITH, H. Morgan", "ROBY, Martha", 
"BROOKS, Mo", "AMODEI, Mark E.", "BONAMICI, Suzanne", "LaMALFA, Doug", 
"HUFFMAN, Jared", "BERA, Ami", "COOK, Paul", "SWALWELL, Eric", 
"BROWNLEY, Julia", "CÁRDENAS, Tony", "RUIZ, Raul", "TAKANO, Mark", 
"LOWENTHAL, Alan", "VARGAS, Juan", "PETERS, Scott", "YOHO, Ted", 
"FRANKEL, Lois", "COLLINS, Doug", "GABBARD, Tulsi", "SCHNEIDER, Brad", 
"DAVIS, Rodney", "BUSTOS, Cheri", "WALORSKI, Jackie", "BROOKS, Susan", 
"BARR, Garland H. (Andy) IV", "KENNEDY, Joseph P. III", "WAGNER, Ann", 
"HORSFORD, Steven", "KUSTER, Ann McLane", "MENG, Grace", "JEFFRIES, Hakeem", 
"MALONEY, Sean Patrick", "COLLINS, Chris", "HUDSON, Richard", 
"MEADOWS, Mark", "HOLDING, George E.B.", "WENSTRUP, Brad", "BEATTY, Joyce", 
"JOYCE, David", "MULLIN, Markwayne", "PERRY, Scott", "CARTWRIGHT, Matt", 
"RICE, Tom", "WEBER, Randy", "CASTRO, Joaquin", "WILLIAMS, Roger", 
"VEASEY, Marc", "VELA, Filemon", "STEWART, Chris", "KILMER, Derek", 
"HECK, Denny", "POCAN, Mark", "KELLY, Robin L.", "KILDEE, Dan", 
"SMITH, Jason", "CLARK, Katherine M.", "BYRNE, Bradley", "PALMER, Gary James", 
"GALLEGO, Ruben", "HILL, French", "DESAULNIER, Mark James", "AGUILAR, Peter Rey", 
"LIEU, Ted", "TORRES, Norma Judith", "BUCK, Kenneth Robert", 
"CARTER, Buddy", "HICE, Jody Brownlow", "LOUDERMILK, Barry D.", 
"ALLEN, Rick W.", "BOST, Mike", "ABRAHAM, Ralph", "GRAVES, Garret", 
"MOULTON, Seth", "MOOLENAAR, John", "DINGELL, Debbie", "LAWRENCE, Brenda L", 
"EMMER, Thomas Earl II", "NORCROSS, Donald", "WATSON COLEMAN, Bonnie", 
"ZELDIN, Lee M", "RICE, Kathleen Maura", "STEFANIK, Elise M", 
"KATKO, John", "WALKER, Bradley Mark", "ROUZER, David", "ADAMS, Alma", 
"BOYLE, Brendan Francis", "RATCLIFFE, John", "HURD, William Ballard", 
"BABIN, Brian", "BEYER, Donald Sternoff Jr.", "NEWHOUSE, Daniel Milton", 
"MOONEY, Alex X.", "GROTHMAN, Glenn", "KELLY, Trent", "LaHOOD, Darin", 
"WESTERMAN, Bruce Eugene", "DAVIDSON, Warren", "COMER, James", 
"EVANS, Dwight", "ARRINGTON, Jodey Cook", "BACON, Donald J.", 
"BANKS, James E.", "BARRAGÁN, Nanette Diaz", "BERGMAN, John", 
"BIGGS, Andrew S.", "BLUNT ROCHESTER, Lisa", "BROWN, Anthony Gregory", 
"BUDD, Theodore Paul", "CARBAJAL, Salud", "CHENEY, Liz", "CORREA, Jose Luis", 
"CRIST, Charlie Joseph Jr.", "DEMINGS, Valdez Butler", "DUNN, Neal Patrick", 
"ESPAILLAT, Adriano J.", "FERGUSON, Anderson Drew IV", "FITZPATRICK, Brian K.", 
"GAETZ, Matthew L. II", "GALLAGHER, Michael", "GONZALEZ, Vicente Jr.", 
"GOTTHEIMER, Josh S.", "HIGGINS, Clay", "HOLLINGSWORTH, Joseph Albert III", 
"JAYAPAL, Pramila", "JOHNSON, Mike", "KHANNA, Rohit", "KRISHNAMOORTHI, S. Raja", 
"KUSTOFF, David", "LAWSON, Alfred Jr.", "MARSHALL, Roger Wayne", 
"MAST, Brian Jeffery", "MCEACHIN, Aston Donald", "MITCHELL, Paul", 
"MURPHY, Stephanie", "O'HALLERAN, Thomas C.", "PANETTA, James Varni", 
"RASKIN, Jamie Ben", "ROONEY, Francis", "RUTHERFORD, John Henry", 
"SMUCKER, Lloyd K.", "SOTO, Darren Michael", "SUOZZI, Thomas", 
"ESTES, Ron", "GIANFORTE, Greg", "NORMAN, Ralph", "GOMEZ, Jimmy", 
"CURTIS, John R.", "LAMB, Conor", "LESKO, Debbie", "CLOUD, Michael", 
"BALDERSON, Troy", "HERN, Kevin", "MORELLE, Joseph D.", "SCANLON, Mary Gay", 
"WILD, Susan", "ALLRED, Colin", "ARMSTRONG, Kelly", "AXNE, Cynthia", 
"BAIRD, James", "BRINDISI, Anthony", "BURCHETT, Timothy", "CASTEN, Sean", 
"CISNEROS, Gil", "CLINE, Benjamin", "COX, TJ", "CRAIG, Angela", 
"CRENSHAW, Daniel", "CROW, Jason", "CUNNINGHAM, Joe", "DAVIDS, Sharice", 
"DEAN, Madeleine", "DELGADO, Antonio", "ESCOBAR, Veronica", "FINKENAUER, Abby", 
"FLETCHER, Elizabeth", "FULCHER, Russell", "GARCÍA, Jesús", 
"GARCIA, Sylvia", "GOLDEN, Jared", "GONZALEZ, Anthony", "GOODEN, Lance", 
"GREEN, Mark", "GUEST, Michael", "HAALAND, Debra", "HAGEDORN, Jim", 
"HARDER, Josh", "HAYES, Jahana", "HILL, Katie", "HORN, Kendra", 
"HOULAHAN, Christina", "JOHNSON, Dustin", "JOYCE, John", "KIM, Andy", 
"LEE, Susie", "LEVIN, Mike", "LEVIN, Andy", "LURIA, Elaine", 
"MALINOWSKI, Tomaz", "McADAMS, Ben", "McBATH, Lucy", "MEUSER, Dan", 
"MILLER, Carol", "MUCARSEL-POWELL, Debbie", "NEGUSE, Joseph", 
"OCASIO-CORTEZ, Alexandria", "OMAR, Ilhan", "PAPPAS, Chris", 
"PENCE, Gregory", "PHILLIPS, Dean", "PORTER, Katie", "PRESSLEY, Ayanna", 
"RESCHENTHALER, Guy", "RIGGLEMAN, Denver", "ROSE, Max", "ROSE, John", 
"ROUDA, Harley", "ROY, Charles", "SCHRIER, Kim", "SHALALA, Donna", 
"SHERRILL, Mikie", "SPANBERGER, Abigail", "SPANO, Ross", "STANTON, Greg", 
"STAUBER, Peter", "STEIL, Bryan", "STEUBE, William", "STEVENS, Haley", 
"TAYLOR, Nicholas", "TIMMONS, William", "TLAIB, Rashida", "TORRES SMALL, Xochitl", 
"TRAHAN, Lori", "TRONE, David", "UNDERWOOD, Lauren", "WALTZ, Michael", 
"WATKINS, Steve", "WEXTON, Jennifer", "WRIGHT, Ron", "WATERS, Maxine", 
"DeLAURO, Rosa L.", "PETERSON, Collin Clark", "SERRANO, José E.", 
"ESHOO, Anna Georges", "ROYBAL-ALLARD, Lucille", "CALVERT, Ken", 
"HASTINGS, Alcee Lamar", "BISHOP, Sanford Dixon, Jr.", "RUSH, Bobby L.", 
"THOMPSON, Bennie", "KING, Peter T.", "NADLER, Jerrold Lewis", 
"VELÁZQUEZ, Nydia M.", "MALONEY, Carolyn Bosher", "LUCAS, Frank D.", 
"LOFGREN, Zoe", "CHABOT, Steve", "DOYLE, Michael F.", "DOGGETT, Lloyd Alton, II", 
"THORNBERRY, William McClellan (Mac)", "JACKSON LEE, Sheila", 
"CUMMINGS, Elijah Eugene", "BLUMENAUER, Earl", "ADERHOLT, Robert", 
"SHERMAN, Brad", "DeGETTE, Diana", "DAVIS, Danny K.", "SHIMKUS, John M.", 
"McGOVERN, James P.", "PASCRELL, William J., Jr.", "BRADY, Kevin Patrick", 
"GRANGER, Kay", "SMITH, Adam", "KIND, Ron", "MEEKS, Gregory W.", 
"LEE, Barbara", "THOMPSON, Michael", "NAPOLITANO, Grace Flores", 
"LARSON, John B.", "SIMPSON, Michael K.", "SCHAKOWSKY, Janice D.", 
"WALDEN, Greg", "DelBENE, Suzan K.", "MASSIE, Thomas", "PAYNE, Donald, Jr.", 
"CLYBURN, James Enos", "JOHNSON, Eddie Bernice", "SCOTT, Robert C.", 
"YOUNG, Donald Edwin", "SENSENBRENNER, Frank James, Jr.", "ROGERS, Harold Dallas (Hal)", 
"SMITH, Christopher Henry", "HOYER, Steny Hamilton", "COOPER, James Hayes Shofner", 
"KAPTUR, Marcia Carolyn (Marcy)", "VISCLOSKY, Peter", "DeFAZIO, Peter Anthony", 
"LEWIS, John R.", "PRICE, David Eugene", "UPTON, Frederick Stephen", 
"PALLONE, Frank, Jr.", "ENGEL, Eliot Lance", "LOWEY, Nita M.", 
"NEAL, Richard Edmund", "SCHIFF, Adam", "DAVIS, Susan A.", "LYNCH, Stephen F.", 
"McCOLLUM, Betty", "GRAVES, Samuel", "LANGEVIN, James", "WILSON, Addison Graves (Joe)", 
"LARSEN, Richard Ray (Rick)", "CLAY, William Lacy, Jr.", "ROGERS, Mike Dennis", 
"GRIJALVA, Raúl M.", "NUNES, Devin", "SÁNCHEZ, Linda T.", "DIAZ-BALART, Mario", 
"SCOTT, David", "CASE, Ed", "KING, Steve", "RUPPERSBERGER, C. A. (Dutch)", 
"BUTTERFIELD, George Kenneth, Jr. (G.K.)", "TURNER, Michael R.", 
"RYAN, Timothy J.", "COLE, Tom", "BURGESS, Michael C.", "CARTER, John R.", 
"BISHOP, Robert (Rob)", "COSTA, Jim", "WASSERMAN SCHULTZ, Debbie", 
"LIPINSKI, Daniel", "CLEAVER, Emanuel, II", "FORTENBERRY, Jeff", 
"HIGGINS, Brian", "FOXX, Virginia Ann", "McHENRY, Patrick T.", 
"GOHMERT, Louie", "GREEN, Al", "McCAUL, Michael T.", "CONAWAY, K. Michael", 
"MARCHANT, Kenny", "CUELLAR, Henry", "McMORRIS RODGERS, Cathy", 
"MOORE, Gwendolynne S. (Gwen)", "MATSUI, Doris", "SIRES, Albio", 
"McNERNEY, Jerry", "MCCARTHY, Kevin", "LAMBORN, Doug", "PERLMUTTER, Ed", 
"COURTNEY, Joe", "CASTOR, Kathy", "BUCHANAN, Vernon G.", "JOHNSON, Hank", 
"LOEBSACK, Dave", "YARMUTH, John", "SARBANES, John", "WALBERG, Tim", 
"SMITH, Adrian", "CLARKE, Yvette Diane", "JORDAN, Jim", "COHEN, Stephen", 
"FOSTER, Bill", "WELCH, Peter", "LATTA, Robert E.", "WITTMAN, Robert J.", 
"CARSON, André", "BILIRAKIS, Gus", "SCALISE, Steve", "SPEIER, Karen Lorraine Jacqueline (Jackie)", 
"KIRKPATRICK, Ann", "McCLINTOCK, Tom", "HIMES, James A.", "POSEY, Bill", 
"GUTHRIE, Brett", "PINGREE, Chellie", "LUETKEMEYER, Blaine", 
"TITUS, Alice (Dina)", "LUJÁN, Ben Ray", "TONKO, Paul", "FUDGE, Marcia L.", 
"SCHRADER, Kurt", "THOMPSON, Glenn", "ROE, David P. (Phil)", 
"OLSON, Pete", "CONNOLLY, Gerald E. (Gerry)", "QUIGLEY, Mike", 
"CHU, Judy", "GARAMENDI, John", "DEUTCH, Theodore E. (Ted)", 
"GRAVES, Tom", "HUNTER, Duncan Duane", "REED, Thomas W. II", 
"SEWELL, Terri", "GOSAR, Paul", "SCHWEIKERT, David", "CRAWFORD, Rick", 
"WOMACK, Steve", "TIPTON, Scott", "WEBSTER, Daniel A.", "WOODALL, Rob", 
"SCOTT, Austin", "KINZINGER, Adam", "BUCSHON, Larry", "RICHMOND, Cedric", 
"HARRIS, Andy", "KEATING, William R.", "HUIZENGA, Bill", "AMASH, Justin", 
"PALAZZO, Steven", "HARTZLER, Vicky", "LONG, Billy", "JOHNSON, Bill", 
"STIVERS, Steve", "GIBBS, Bob", "KELLY, Mike", "MARINO, Thomas A.", 
"CICILLINE, David N.", "DUNCAN, Jeff", "FLEISCHMANN, Chuck", 
"DESJARLAIS, Scott", "FLORES, Bill", "HERRERA BEUTLER, Jaime", 
"McKINLEY, David", "DUFFY, Sean", "GRIFFITH, H. Morgan", "ROBY, Martha", 
"BROOKS, Mo", "AMODEI, Mark E.", "BONAMICI, Suzanne", "LaMALFA, Doug", 
"HUFFMAN, Jared", "BERA, Ami", "COOK, Paul", "SWALWELL, Eric", 
"BROWNLEY, Julia", "RUIZ, Raul", "TAKANO, Mark", "LOWENTHAL, Alan", 
"VARGAS, Juan", "PETERS, Scott", "YOHO, Ted", "FRANKEL, Lois", 
"COLLINS, Doug", "GABBARD, Tulsi", "SCHNEIDER, Brad", "DAVIS, Rodney", 
"BUSTOS, Cheri", "WALORSKI, Jackie", "BROOKS, Susan", "BARR, Garland H. (Andy) IV", 
"KENNEDY, Joseph P. III", "WAGNER, Ann", "HORSFORD, Steven", 
"KUSTER, Ann McLane", "MENG, Grace", "JEFFRIES, Hakeem", "MALONEY, Sean Patrick", 
"COLLINS, Chris", "HUDSON, Richard", "MEADOWS, Mark", "HOLDING, George E.B.", 
"WENSTRUP, Brad", "BEATTY, Joyce", "JOYCE, David", "MULLIN, Markwayne", 
"PERRY, Scott", "CARTWRIGHT, Matt", "RICE, Tom", "WEBER, Randy", 
"CASTRO, Joaquin", "WILLIAMS, Roger", "VEASEY, Marc", "VELA, Filemon", 
"STEWART, Chris", "KILMER, Derek", "HECK, Denny", "POCAN, Mark", 
"KELLY, Robin L.", "KILDEE, Dan", "SMITH, Jason", "CLARK, Katherine M.", 
"BYRNE, Bradley", "PALMER, Gary James", "GALLEGO, Ruben", "HILL, French", 
"DESAULNIER, Mark James", "AGUILAR, Peter Rey", "LIEU, Ted", 
"TORRES, Norma Judith", "BUCK, Kenneth Robert", "CARTER, Buddy", 
"HICE, Jody Brownlow", "LOUDERMILK, Barry D.", "ALLEN, Rick W.", 
"BOST, Mike", "ABRAHAM, Ralph", "GRAVES, Garret", "MOULTON, Seth", 
"MOOLENAAR, John", "DINGELL, Debbie", "LAWRENCE, Brenda L", "EMMER, Thomas Earl II", 
"NORCROSS, Donald", "WATSON COLEMAN, Bonnie", "ZELDIN, Lee M", 
"RICE, Kathleen Maura", "STEFANIK, Elise M", "KATKO, John", "WALKER, Bradley Mark", 
"ROUZER, David", "ADAMS, Alma", "BOYLE, Brendan Francis", "RATCLIFFE, John", 
"HURD, William Ballard", "BABIN, Brian", "BEYER, Donald Sternoff Jr.", 
"NEWHOUSE, Daniel Milton", "MOONEY, Alex X.", "GROTHMAN, Glenn", 
"KELLY, Trent", "LaHOOD, Darin", "WESTERMAN, Bruce Eugene", "DAVIDSON, Warren", 
"COMER, James", "EVANS, Dwight", "ARRINGTON, Jodey Cook", "BACON, Donald J.", 
"BANKS, James E.", "BARRAGÁN, Nanette Diaz", "BERGMAN, John", 
"BIGGS, Andrew S.", "BLUNT ROCHESTER, Lisa", "BROWN, Anthony Gregory", 
"BUDD, Theodore Paul", "CARBAJAL, Salud", "CHENEY, Liz", "CORREA, Jose Luis", 
"CRIST, Charlie Joseph Jr.", "DEMINGS, Valdez Butler", "DUNN, Neal Patrick", 
"ESPAILLAT, Adriano J.", "FERGUSON, Anderson Drew IV", "FITZPATRICK, Brian K.", 
"GAETZ, Matthew L. II", "GALLAGHER, Michael", "GONZALEZ, Vicente Jr.", 
"GOTTHEIMER, Josh S.", "HIGGINS, Clay", "HOLLINGSWORTH, Joseph Albert III", 
"JAYAPAL, Pramila", "JOHNSON, Mike", "KHANNA, Rohit", "KRISHNAMOORTHI, S. Raja", 
"KUSTOFF, David", "LAWSON, Alfred Jr.", "MARSHALL, Roger Wayne", 
"MAST, Brian Jeffery", "MCEACHIN, Aston Donald", "MITCHELL, Paul", 
"MURPHY, Stephanie", "O'HALLERAN, Thomas C.", "PANETTA, James Varni", 
"RASKIN, Jamie Ben", "ROONEY, Francis", "RUTHERFORD, John Henry", 
"SOTO, Darren Michael", "SUOZZI, Thomas", "ESTES, Ron", "GIANFORTE, Greg", 
"NORMAN, Ralph", "GOMEZ, Jimmy", "CURTIS, John R.", "LAMB, Conor", 
"LESKO, Debbie", "CLOUD, Michael", "BALDERSON, Troy", "HERN, Kevin", 
"MORELLE, Joseph D.", "SCANLON, Mary Gay", "ALLRED, Colin", "ARMSTRONG, Kelly", 
"AXNE, Cynthia", "BAIRD, James", "BRINDISI, Anthony", "BURCHETT, Timothy", 
"CASTEN, Sean", "CISNEROS, Gil", "CLINE, Benjamin", "COX, TJ", 
"CRAIG, Angela", "CRENSHAW, Daniel", "CROW, Jason", "CUNNINGHAM, Joe", 
"DAVIDS, Sharice", "DEAN, Madeleine", "DELGADO, Antonio", "ESCOBAR, Veronica", 
"FINKENAUER, Abby", "FLETCHER, Elizabeth", "FULCHER, Russell", 
"GARCÍA, Jesús", "GARCIA, Sylvia", "GOLDEN, Jared", "GONZALEZ, Anthony", 
"GOODEN, Lance", "GREEN, Mark", "GUEST, Michael", "HAALAND, Debra", 
"HAGEDORN, Jim", "HARDER, Josh", "HAYES, Jahana", "HILL, Katie", 
"HORN, Kendra", "HOULAHAN, Christina", "JOHNSON, Dustin", "JOYCE, John", 
"KIM, Andy", "LEE, Susie", "LEVIN, Mike", "LEVIN, Andy", "LURIA, Elaine", 
"MALINOWSKI, Tomaz", "McADAMS, Ben", "McBATH, Lucy", "MEUSER, Dan", 
"MILLER, Carol", "MUCARSEL-POWELL, Debbie", "NEGUSE, Joseph", 
"OCASIO-CORTEZ, Alexandria", "OMAR, Ilhan", "PAPPAS, Chris", 
"PENCE, Gregory", "PHILLIPS, Dean", "PORTER, Katie", "PRESSLEY, Ayanna", 
"RESCHENTHALER, Guy", "RIGGLEMAN, Denver", "ROSE, Max", "ROSE, John", 
"ROUDA, Harley", "ROY, Charles", "SCHRIER, Kim", "SHALALA, Donna", 
"SHERRILL, Mikie", "SLOTKIN, Elissa", "SPANBERGER, Abigail", 
"SPANO, Ross", "STANTON, Greg", "STAUBER, Peter", "STEIL, Bryan", 
"STEUBE, William", "STEVENS, Haley", "TAYLOR, Nicholas", "TIMMONS, William", 
"TLAIB, Rashida", "TORRES SMALL, Xochitl"), session = c(116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116), sessionvote = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), voter_response = c("n", 
"n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", 
"y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", 
"n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", 
"n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "n", 
"y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", 
"y", "n", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", 
"y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", 
"n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
"n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", 
"y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", 
"y", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
"n", "y", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", 
"y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", 
"y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "n", "n", 
"n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", 
"y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", 
"y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
"y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", 
"y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n", 
"y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", 
"n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", 
"y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", 
"y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", 
"y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", 
"y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", 
"y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", 
"n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", 
"n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "n", 
"n", "y", "n", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", 
"y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", 
"n", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", 
"n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", 
"n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", 
"y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", 
"n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", 
"n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", "y", "y", 
"n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", 
"y", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", "y", "n", 
"y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", 
"y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "n", 
"y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
"y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", 
"y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
"n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "n", "n", 
"y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y", "n", "n", 
"n", "y", "n", "n", "y", "y")), row.names = c(NA, -800L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What is the difference betwen sessionvote and voter_response?

Comment: Your data is not consistent: some individual vote twice in the same session and sessionvote; i guess those duplicates should be removed

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto, I added an explanation in the post. Basically, sessionvote is the ID number for each vote that was held during the session. Several votes could be held during the same session, so sessionvote variable indicates which vote from that session is being referenced. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Maël, you are right. There were a couple typos in the sample dataset I created. i have fixed the sample table, but I have also included a dput() subset of my actual data now.

Comment: @Iwe I can write a python vesion, for the record, if you like.

Comment: @Iwe What is the "equal" condition for two voters to have same response? DO they must have the same "sessionvote" and "voter_response"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution mainly using `combn`:

```r
#Create a wide data.frame with 1 row per session (can be done otherwise)
nms <- unique(df$name)
df$voter_response <- ifelse(tolower(df$voter_response) == "y", 1, 0)
dfwd <- 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = "name", values_from = "voter_response") |> 
  subset(select = nms)

#Create the distance matrix
mat <- diag(ncol(dfwd))
colnames(mat) <- rownames(mat) <- nms

#Iterate a function over the combinations of columns: the function
#looks for the mean similarity value
comb <- 
  combn(ncol(dfwd), m = 2,
        FUN = \(k) mean(dfwd[, k[1]] == dfwd[, k[2]], na.rm = TRUE))

#Assign these values to both the upper and lower triangles of the matrix.
mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- comb

#Output
            Tim Dave     Larry John
Tim   1.0000000  0.5 0.6666667    0
Dave  0.5000000  1.0 0.0000000    1
Larry 0.6666667  0.0 1.0000000    0
John  0.0000000  1.0 0.0000000    1
```

---

Data:

```r
df <- read.table(h=T,text="name session sessionvote voter_response
Tim 116 1   Y
Tim 116 2   N
Tim 117 1   Y
Tim 117 2   Y
Dave    117 1   N
Dave    117 2   Y
Larry   116 1   Y
Larry   116 2   Y
Larry   117 1   Y
John    117 1   N")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Maël. However, I've run into a problem when trying to use the reshape command: ```Error in `x[r, vars, drop = drop]`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Columns `ROGERS, Harold Dallas (Hal)`, `SMITH, Christopher Henry`, `HOYER, Steny Hamilton`, `KAPTUR, Marcia Carolyn (Marcy)`, `VISCLOSKY, Peter`, etc. don't exist.``` I've now included dput() data with a subset of my real data.

Comment: I've reran the analysis with your data, and made some edits to your data it should be working now

Comment: Still getting the error: ```> dfwd <- 
+   reshape(data = sampledata, direction = "wide",
+           idvar = c("session", "sessionvote"),
+           timevar = "name", varying = nms) |> 
+   subset(select = nms)
Error in `x[r, vars, drop = drop]`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Columns `SENSENBRENNER, Frank James, Jr.`, `ROGERS, Harold Dallas (Hal)`, `SMITH, Christopher Henry`, `HOYER, Steny Hamilton`, `KAPTUR, Marcia Carolyn (Marcy)`, etc. don't exist.
Backtrace:
 1. base::subset(...)
 2. base::subset.data.frame(...)
 4. tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(x, r, vars, drop = drop)```

Comment: I changed `reshape`  to `pivot_wider`, much easier to use. This should work no